# Исключение определенных случаев из результата сопоставления

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pcre

```php
$regex = /(^)(\[(.*)\]) (.*)$/;
```

Regex берет все сообщения чата вида:

```
[Помощь] Джон: ...
```

Проблема в том, что в чате также встречаются строки вида:

```
[      ] Служебная информация: ...
[ >Важно< ] ...
[ >>>  ] ...
[ <<<  ] ...
```

Т. е., по сути, мне надо исключить строки, где в начале между `[` и `]`:

- Есть только пробелы и/или знаки `>` и `<`
- Есть только надпись `важно`, с пробелами и знаками `<`, `>` или без

При этом пробел, знаки `>` и `<` могут встречаться в других случаях, но если между `[` и `]` также есть и другие символы, то такую строку нужно брать

```
[Общий] Джон: Привет
[ > СТАТУС < ] ...
[ >>> 45] ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вроде:

```
$regex = /^\[(?![\s<>]*\])(.*?)\] (.*)$/;
```

https://regex101.com/r/cA4vH0/1